# Horizontal list items - fit to 100% with even spacing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a simple list and i am trying to get the list items to be evenly spaced horizontally, but still fill 100% of the width of the container regardless of the width of the container.

I do not want each list item to be of equal width, but instead the spacing between each list item to be even:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b6muX/1/

Also the number of list items might be dynamic and not the same as the number in my example.

Can this be done without js?

Here is my markup and css:

```
<ul>
    <li>This is menu item 1</li>
    <li>Number 2</li>
    <li>Item Number 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

and the following css:

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: #cacaca;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10%;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    background: #fafafa;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The new CSS flexbox specification would be the solution to your problem :)

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch; /* Default */
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    background: #cacaca;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    flex: 0 1 auto; /* Default */
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>This is menu item 1</li>
    <li>Number 2</li>
    <li>Item Number 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/b6muX/3/

If you would allow me to indulge myself in a bit of explanation:

1. `display: flex` on the parent tells the parent to adopt the CSS flexbox model
2. `align-items: stretch` tells the parent that its children should stretch to the full height of the row. This is the default value of the property.
3. `justify-content: space-between` is the **magic** here — it instructs the parent to distribute remaining space left after laying out the children between them.

On the children:

1. `flex: 0 1 auto` on the children tells them that:

   - `flex-grow: 0`: Do no grow, otherwise they will fill up the parent
   - `flex-shrink: 1`: Shrink when necessary, to prevent overflowing (you can turn this off by setting to 0.
   - `flex-basis: auto`: Widths of children element are calculated automatically based on their content. If you want fixed, equal width children element, simply set it to `100%`.

You can adjust the padding to the `<li>` element as of when you see please.

---

### Old CSS method: `text-align: justify`

The old method, while working perfectly, is a little more cumbersome as it requires you to reset the font-size in the unordered list element to eliminate spacing between child elements. It also requires you to render an pseudo-element to ensure that the content overflows the first row for text justification to kick in (remember that the default behavior of justified text is that a row that is not 100% will not be justified).

```css
ul {
    font-size: 0; /* Eliminate spacing between inline block elements */
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
    background: #cacaca;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul:after {
    content: 'abc';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fafafa;
    font-size: 1rem; /* Reuse root element's font size */
}
p {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>This is menu item 1</li>
    <li>Number 2</li>
    <li>Item Number 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/b6muX/5/

Comment: looks perfect! but i need to support down to ie8

Comment: @MartyWallace Tough luck — [IE only supports flexbox from IE10 and above](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). Below that you will either have to use jQuery for a perfect bullet-proof solution, or can use messy CSS (like declaring list items as `inline-block` and using `text-align: justify` on the parent.

Comment: @MartyWallace See possible CSS fallback for IE in updated answer.

Comment: In IE11 (on Windows 10), the original solution worked for me, but the "Old CSS method" did not.  Both worked fine in Chrome and Edge for me.

Comment: The first solution almost works for me, sometimes one <li> element takes up a lot more space than the others, they are not evenly distributed across the pages width.

Comment: @Dennis They are meant to size according to the content of the `<li>` element. If you want equal width for all of them, you will have to change the `flex-basis` property to use `100%`: I've already addressed that in the question.

Comment: How can I make this have the spacing on the side too? The `text-align`: justify example would look like this: `|a   |   a   |   a|`. How do I get it to look like this: `|   a   |   a   |   a   |`?

Comment: Use `justify-content: space-around` and ensure that the flex children don’t grow to occupy all width, ie use `flex-grow: 0`.

Comment: Thanks, I use `width: 125px` so I dont need `flex-grow: 0`, unless I am mistaken

Comment: Under "display: flex;" I would recommend adding "flex-wrap: wrap;" to handle responsive/mobile screen sizes.